# Не получается вывести структуру

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня задание сделать структуру, потом отсортировать ее и т.д.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На последние два пункта не обращайте внимания, еще не сделал.

Я вроде нашел способ  сделать структуру, но вывести нормально не могу

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define N 3

struct STUDENT {
    char name[30];
    int group;
    int ses[5];

};

int sum, sra;
int *p = &sra;

int cmp( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    return ( *( int * )p1 - * ( int * )p2 );
}

int main()
{
    STUDENT stud1[N];

    for( int st = 0; st < N; st++ ) {
        cout << "Input first name: ";
        cin.getline( stud1[st].name, 30 );
        cout << "Input number of group: ";
        cin >> stud1[st].group;

        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            cout << "Input mark " << i + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> stud1[st].ses[i];
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
            sum = sra = 0;
            sum = stud1[st].ses[i] + stud1[st].ses[i + 1];
            sra = sum / 5;
        }

        cout << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    qsort( p, N, sizeof( STUDENT ), cmp );
    int fl = 1;

    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        int j = 0;

        while( ( j < 5 ) && ( stud1[i].ses[j] != 2 ) ) {
            j++;
        }

        if( j < 5 ) {
            fl = 0;
            cout << "Student " << stud1[i].name << " (group " << stud1[i].group <<
                 ") have mark 2" << endl;
        }
    }

    if( fl ) {
        cout << "No students, which have mark 2" << endl;
    }

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Я пытался вывести так:

```
for( int st = 0; st < N; st++ ) {
    cout << stud1[st].name << " " << stud1[st].group << " " << 
        stud1[st].ses[i] << endl;
}
```

и вот так

```
for( int st = 0; st < N; st++ ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        cout << stud1[st].name << " " << stud1[st].group << " " << 
        stud1[st].ses[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Но в первом случае последний столб вообще не выводит а во втором каждая запись повторяется по 5 раз(кол-во оценок)

Помогите пожалуйста найти решение)

И еще только что выяснил что сортировка почему то не работает, не подскажите в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Я тут еще только что выяснил что сортировка почему то не работает, не могли бы вы подсказать в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так, с вложенными циклами:

```
for (int st=0; st<N; st++)
{
    cout << stud1[st].name << " " << stud1[st].group << " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        cout << stud1[st].ses[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Кстати, а что вы тут делаете:

```
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        sum = sra = 0;
        sum = stud1[st].ses[i] + stud1[st].ses[i + 1];
        sra = sum / 5;
    }
```

Что-то странный код... Если бы считался средний балл, то логично было бы ожидать

```
    sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        sum += stud1[st].ses[i];
    }
    sra = sum / 5;
```

Сортировка же должна использовать

```
int cmp( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    return ( *( int * )p1 - * ( int * )p2 );
}
```

Которая сравнивает СТУДЕНТОВ. Вы сравниваете непонятно что. Например, сравнение по имени должно иметь вид

```
int cmp( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    return (strcmp(((STUDENT*)p1)->name,((STUDENT*)p2)->name);
}
```

а сама функция - вызываться как

```
qsort(stud1,N,sizeof(STUDENT),cmp);
```

Но учтите - что это у вас C, но никак не C++...

Comment: Я тут еще  только что выяснил что сортировка почему то не работает, не могли бы вы подсказать в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте так, как я написал. Правда, не знаю, по какому полю вы хотите сортировать.

Comment: Именно по среднему баллу среди 5 оценок, именно для этого и ищу его. Если бы по имени то я это бы сделал, а так вообще запутался...
А как понимать что это язык С но не С++?

Comment: Да просто у вас нигде не используются специфичные возможности C++... А по средней оценке - добавьте поле средней оценки в структуру `STUDENT`, скажем, это поле `sra`. После вычислений сортируйте с функцией `return (((STUDENT*)p1)->sra - ((STUDENT*)p2)->sra);`